# A typescript project with many submodules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a project where my goal is very simple, expose it as a library with typed definitions included.

Acutally, this project compiles and works well without it, the typescript compiler also, export all definitions.

To understand my question, let me introduce a small part of that project to make things more simpler here.

#### Project Structure

```
project root
│   tsconfig.json
│   package.json
│   ...  
│
└─── src
│   │
│   │ index.ts
│   └── Elements
│   │   │ Elements.ts
│   │   │ package.json
│   │   │
│   │   └── Button
│   │   │ Button.tsx
│   │   │ package.json
│   │   │
│   │   └── Toast
│   │   │ Toast.tsx
│   │   │ package.json
│   │   │
│   └── Forms
│   │   │ Forms.ts
│   │   │ package.json
│   │   │
│   │   └── InputText
│   │   │ InputText.tsx
│   │   │ package.json
│   │   │
│   │   └── DatePicker
│   │   │ DatePicker.tsx
│   │   │ package.json
```

In general, all `package.json` files inside a category, looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "category-or-component-name",
  "version": "0",
  "main": "CategoryOrComponent.ts",
  "types": "CategoryOrComponent.ts"
}
```

#### Categories

Inside `src`, there are some *"categories"* of components, each category hosts a `package.json`, a `{CategoryName}.ts` file and a list of components.

A category implementation, looks like this:

```
export { default as Button } from './Button'
export { default as Toast } from './Toast'
```

#### Components

There is no much secrets here, each component has its proper implementation at `Component.tsx` and the `package.json` file inside each component's folder is almost the same of the `package.json` file founded inside a category.

Here a example of component:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export interface Props {
  children?: string | JSX.Element;
}

export default class Button extends React.PureComponent<Props, {}> {
  public render (): JSX.Element {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
      <button>{children}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

#### Output

After export the source as lib, the typscript provides the type definitions like below.

```
project root
│   tsconfig.json
│   package.json
│   ...  
│
└─── lib
│   │
│   │ index.d.ts
│   └── Elements
│   │   │ Elements.d.ts
│   │   │
│   │   └── Button
│   │   │ Button.d.ts
│   │   │
│   │   └── Toast
│   │   │ Toast.d.ts
│   │   │
│   └── Forms
│   │   │ Forms.d.ts
│   │   │
│   │   └── InputText
│   │   │ InputText.d.ts
│   │   │
│   │   └── DatePicker
│   │   │ DatePicker.d.ts
```

#### Definition

The definitions inside category and components are never loaded, because the `.d.ts` files, don't point to the `.d.ts` files, instead, they points to folder.

Let's see a example of definition:

```
export interface Props {
  children?: string | JSX.Element;
}

export default class Button extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<Props>;
  private handleOnClick;
  private handleOnMouseOver;
  private handleOnMouseOut;
  private handleOnTouchStart;
  private handleOnTouchEnd;
  render(): JSX.Element;
}
```

#### Problem

Any `.d.ts` file generated, on import some resource, points to folder like this:

```
import Button from './Elements/Button'
```

This means the consumer of that lib, will never find the `Button.d.ts` file because, there is no `package.json` inside it.

At `src` works because each folder has a `package.json` file. The responsability of `package.json` file here is to indicate to node and typescript, who is the index file, simple like that.

So my question is, there is some feature in `tsc` to bundle or maybe to improve module resolution?

Thanks